# What is the change event on a time spinner in JQueryUI?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, time

I'm trying to make the time spinner from the [JQueryUI example page](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/#time) update a div whenever it is changed. I can make a standard spinner work but I can't figure out how to access the event from the modified time version of the spinner.

There's a (not) working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/r5GYD/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //I need this to be more widely available so it's declared out here
    var time = 'time';
    //check that the JQuery call actually does what it's supposed to
    $('#time').html(time);

    $.widget("ui.timespinner", $.ui.spinner, {
        options: {
            // seconds
            step: 60 * 1000,
            // hours
            page: 60
        },

        _parse: function (value) {
            if (typeof value === "string") {
                // already a timestamp
                if (Number(value) == value) {
                    return Number(value);
                }
                return +Globalize.parseDate(value);
            }
            return value;
        },

        _format: function (value) {
            return Globalize.format(new Date(value), "t");
        }
    });

    $("#timespinner").timespinner();
    $("#timespinner").change(function () { //TODO not working :(
        time = $(this).val();
        console.log(time);
        $('#time').html(time);
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

Ok, right, so the timespinner is a custom widget done inline. So the options are weird. In this part of the code add:

```
$.widget("ui.timespinner", $.ui.spinner, {
    options: {
        // seconds
        step: 60 * 1000,
        // hours
        page: 60,
        change: function () { 
                  time = $(this).val();
                  console.log(time);
                  $('#time').html(time);
               }
    }
    //rest of code
```

Though you may want to use the "spin" option instead of the change option:

```
$.widget("ui.timespinner", $.ui.spinner, {
    options: {
        // seconds
        step: 60 * 1000,
        // hours
        page: 60,
        spin: function () { 
                  time = $(this).val();
                  console.log(time);
                  $('#time').html(time);
               }
    }
    //rest of code
```

Comment: When I test these in the fiddle neither of them work. The first doesn't show as a time spinner, the second shows a time spinner but doesn't make anything happen.

Comment: You... Are absolutely correct. timespinner isn't even documented on their site.

Comment: ok, upon closer inspection, I see what is going on. Please see revision in answer.

Comment: Great, thanks! I spent ages looking at it not changing and then realised that 'change' only fires when it loses focus! Spin it is then.